# A question about IHttpModule!! Read ahead

Tags: asp.net

Lets Suppose that I have made a custom authentication module that inherits IHttpModule class.
Now the catch here is that how do I pass to this new module username and password which are in the form of textboxes placed on a page. For authentication module , I have never reaached to the stage where I can take user input from the login page and play with those variables in my authentication module.

To summarize, what I mean is I have not reached to a page which takes user input and then plays with it in authentication module. What I mean to ask is how do I reach to the login page and use the authentication module for authentication.

Hope I have made it clear. If not I can explain further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your module is checking if user is logged in or not. It doesn't apply credentials to the current session. In order to do that, you should catch it on an event, for instance when login button is clicked you can fire an event which is located in your module and you can do whatever you want to do.

Comment: How do I fire a module event on my login page?

Comment: reading the following article will help a lot. http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/170/developing-a-module-using-net/

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to check the current context's form collection for the user name/password fields, via:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["UserName"]
```

If its available... I think the current application instance is passed in as a param, where you can get the context through that too.

HTH.

Comment: My friend you didnt understand what I said.  My module is running before the login page is opened. I dont have the userid/pass to pplay with!!!

Comment: In the `Init` method an `HttpApplication` is passed and from there you can register to receive the `BeginRequest` event. When that gets raised an instantiated `HttpApplication` is given and you can use the `Context` property as above.

Comment: And you'd have to except the login page from your module

Comment: Or actually, only parse POST requests on the login page

Comment: Do you understand the basics of an HttpModule? Here's a walkthrough that shows how to register for events. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673.aspx

Comment: Here's another link that builds an Authentication module: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-security/AspNetCustomAuth.aspx

Comment: Chris , hear me out. What I understand is that Modules run before the handlers. My question is how do I take the input values before the module starts to run.

Comment: @Chandan Khatwani, I don't understand what "take the input values before the module starts to run" means. There's nothing before the module, that's the first thing in the ASP.Net pipeline (after the server itself). http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/011404-1.aspx